# In python, return a value from the interactive REPL in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter, read-eval-print-loop

Could we return values from REPL in Jupyter?

```
import code
def console_exit():
    raise SystemExit
try:
    code.InteractiveConsole(locals={"exit": console_exit}).interact()
except SystemExit:
    pass
```

Comment: Assign the value to a variable, and put that variable on its own on the last line of a cell. The last line of a cell is always echo-ed in Jupyter, unless followed by a semi-colon.

Comment: I need the last line to call `exit()` in order to get out of the REPL. I am trying to pull out values defined inside the REPL outside into the cell.

Comment: Misunderstood. But it seems very strange to run the interactive interpreter inside a Jupyter cell, since the latter itself is interactive.

Comment: But no: the interpreter is kind-of standalone, and just like the normal interpreter, you can't communicate to the outside world (usually the shell for the standard interpreter) with just variables. You'd need a file, a socket or something similar (perhaps even environment variables could work).

Comment: I see. I wanted to make a script where an interactive session gives users the space to define new functions / variables that the script could use after the user exits the session. I will look into using files. Thanks, I appreciate your help.